# Elements in the proof of the Levy-Khinchin formula for i.d. distributions.

Tags: probability

I was working through the proof of the existence of the Levy-Khinchin formula contained in Achim Klenke's Probability Theory (page 340 of the second edition, page 336 in the first edition).  His proof is quite elegant, at least according to my personal taste, and it starts from the definition of the log-characteristic function:
$$ \psi(t) = \log \int e^{itx}\, \mu(dx), $$
where $\mu $ is an infinitely divisible probability distribution. I can follow his proof, but this is based on the fact that the author claims that
$$ \text{Im}(\psi(t)) \hskip 5pt \text{is an odd function, and} $$
$$ \text{Re}(\psi(t))\le 0. $$
I understand that one can write the function $e^{itx} $ as $\cos(tx) + i\sin(tx), $ which yields 
$$ \psi(t) = \log\biggl( \int \cos(tx)\, \mu(dx) + i \int \sin(tx)\, \mu(dx)\biggl) $$
and that one could use the formula for the complex log
$$ \log(a+ib) = \sqrt{a^2+b^2} +i(\arctan(b/a) +2n\pi). $$
However, now I do not seem to be able to infer the conclusion stated in the textbook. If $\mu $ were the Lebesgue measure then, yes, I can see it, but with $\mu $ being any (infinitely divisible) probability measure, I cannot. Am I going the wrong way or am I missing something that might be actually very easy? Any help would be appreciated. I can redo the proof if I take the two statements as given, but I do not seem to be able to justify them.

Thank you.

Maurice

---

Added on 12 November 2014.......

Actually, I realized that I was just over-complicating the issue by writing
$ \psi(t) $ in terms of sine and cosine. Avoiding that, my question is quite straightforward and I apologize for taking up anybody's time with it.

Basically, if $z = \int e^{itx}\, \mu(dx), $ then
$$ \text{Re}(\psi(t)) = \log|z| = \log\biggl(\biggl| \int e^{itx}\, \mu(dx)\biggl| \biggl). $$
But, since
$$   \biggl| \int e^{itx}\, \mu(dx) \biggl| \le \int |e^{itx}|\, \mu(dx) \le \int 1\, \mu(dx) = 1, $$
it follows that  $\text{Re}(\psi(t)) \le 0. $

Maurice